# How to get Excel 2010 to automatically change the row numbers in a function

Tags: excel

I am computing a final report and I need to compute the value of a specific column in a spreadsheet of 150 rows

The function which i wrote is

```
=((SUM(I6:W6)/75)*.35*4)+(Y6*.1)+(Z6*.15)+(AA6*.3)+((AB6*4)/10 *.1)
```

is working fine but then I am forced to copy it to each row of that specific column and update the row numbers to get the correct answer.

For example ,if I wanted to calculate the value for row number 16 for that column,I would have to manually enter this :

```
=((SUM(I16:W16)/75)*.35*4)+(Y16*.1)+(Z16*.15)+(AA16*.3)+((AB16*4)/10 *.1)
```

This process is going to take a lot of time if I do it for all the records,any inputs on how to automatically get excel to update the row numbers ?

Thanks !!

Comment: In which cell are you putting the answer to your calculation? Why can't you you just copy the formula down the rows? For example, if the result of your formula is in cell A6 why can't you copy down to cell A16 to get the correct result for row 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double-click the lower-right-little-black-square that will appear on the cell containing the formula

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard feature of Excel.

You have just to copy "dragging".

I am looking for a video to post here.

Edit. Videos

http://www.metacafe.com/watch/1084306/excel_trick/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoQmaLh2L-A

HTH!